# Update a field in view on interval in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple application that tracks customers: name (and/or id) and start time. It also shows each customer's time total and shows the bill based on how much time a customer has spent.

I initially wrote the application in vanilla JS, but I am rewriting it in Angular now. I am having trouble coming up with a good way to update the time total in the view. Here is what I have at the moment:

Model:

```
.factory('Customer', function () {
    function Customer(id, name, start, discount) {
        this.name = name || '';
        this.id = id || null;
        this.start = start || Date.now();
        this.discount = parseFloat(discount) || 0;

        this.orders = [];
    }

    Customer.prototype.addOrder = function (order) {
        this.orders.push(order);
    };
    Customer.prototype.deleteOrder = function (order) {
        var index = this.orders.indexOf(order);
        if (index > -1) {
            this.orders.splice(index, 1);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Order deletion error - order not found.');
        }
    };

    Customer.fromObj = function (obj) {
        return new Customer(
            obj.id,
            obj.name,
            obj.start,
            obj.discount)
    };

    return Customer;
})
```

Part of the controller:

```
$scope.addCustomer = function () {
    // add current time
    $scope.newCustomer.start = Date.now();
    // push the customer to container
    $scope.customers.push(Customer.fromObj($scope.newCustomer));
}
```

View:

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers" ng-click="customerDetails(customer)">
    <td ng-bind="customer.name"></td>
    <td ng-bind="customer.id"></td>
    <td>SHOW TIME HERE</td>
    <td>SHOW MONEY HERE</td>
</tr>
```

*The problem:*
Initially, I each customer object had it's own intervals for updating time and money values, like so:

```
this.timeTotal = 0;
this.moneyTotal = 0;
this.timeInterval = setInterval(this.updateTime.bind(this), 1000);
this.moneyInterval = setInterval(this.updateMoney.bind(this), 1000);
```

along with a function to clear the intervals on destruction:

```
Customer.prototype.clearIntervals = function(){
    clearInterval(this.timeInterval);
    clearInterval(this.moneyInterval);
}
```

This way, I could `<td ng-bind="customer.timeTotal">`. **However**, I believe, that time-/money- tracking should take place in the view (*am I wrong?*). Examples I've found so far seem to all talk about updating a single value using `$interval`.

I am pondering over a few possible solutions:

- create a directive like `<td track-time="customer">`
- do it using some sort of function in the parent controller
- use the old way, where each object has an interval and a property that stores the timeTotal
- use events
- maybe abything else?

I hope you could help me with choosing a decision that seems better suited to this situation, or you could suggest some other way that I have not thought of yet.

Note, that the only fields that need backing up to a storage are `name`,`id`,`start`,`discount`, which is part of the reason why i'm reluctant to adding more properties to the `Customer` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the view model should preferably be done in controllers.

If you make each customer a directive (or component if you are using angular 1.5), then they will each have their own scope where you can handle the intervals.

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers" ng-click="customerDetails(customer)">
    <customer customer-ref="customer"></customer>
</div>
```

customerCtrl:

```
$interval(updateTime, 1000)

function updateTime(){
    // $scope.time = $scope.customer.foo etc...  
}
```

You should use $interval rather than setInterval.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval